# onDestroy, killing a running thread

Tags: android

I have a method like this in my class which extends `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i("onDestory: ", "Inside OnDestory!");
    bluetoothCommunicator.destroyedApp();
    super.onDestroy(); 
}
```

The method `destroyedApp()` look like this:

```
public void destroyedApp() {
        if(server != null)
            server.destroy();   
}
```

Where `server` is an Instance of a class which extends `Thread`

Here is the scenario:

I'm opening the application for the first time, inside my `onCreate` method, I create a new instance of the bluetooth class which sets up the `BluetoothServerSocket`, this works fine and I'm able to transfer files to my phone.

This also works when I have my application in the background, because the thread is still alive.

**But**

When I'm killing the application, according to the `Activity Life Cycle`

[image: Activity Life Cycle here]

The `onDestroy()` method should be called by the Android Framework. And when I'm launching the application once more, the `onCreate` method should be called, but it doesnt seems that an instance of the `BluetoothServerSocket` is being created. I have no `LogCat` info, because the device which sends the bluetooth file, only says:

```
Error Log:
Write Error: 
Transport endpoint is not connected
__obex_connect:
error=-2
Unable to connect to the server
Error
```

Which tells me that the `BluetoothServerSocket` is not "alive"

Any suggestion on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: How come you're calling super.onStop() from onDestroy()?

Comment: it was just a mistake, changed it to `super.OnDestroy()` but nothing changed in the behaviour of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is generally no guarantee that the onDestroy() method will be called at all. According to the docs:

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things around while the rest of its application is still running. There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.
>
>     Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

So I would first test if it is being called reliably.

Also, you are callling `super.onStop()` in your `onDestroy()`. It should be `super.onDestroy()`

Answer (score 2):

Since I cannot comment, I am posting here.
As, commented by Egor I dont think you can call onStop() from within onDestroy(), Android will itself call onStop() following onPause() depending on the memory.
Now, note that stop(), suspend() and destroy() methods of thread are deprecated, the only safe way of terminating a thread is to have thread exit its run().
Now, when you are calling server.destroy(), there is a possibility that it still holds some link in the memory and therefore Garbage collector will not be able to garbage collect your activity. Hence, I believe this could be the possible reason why your onDestroy is not called.
Point me if I am worng.

Answer (score 1):

How are you killing your application? I was looking for a solution for your problem in the `Application` class and I came across this information about the `onTerminate()` method:

> This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; **no user code** (including this callback) **is executed when doing so**.

I remember I had a similar problem in one of my apps, where some components' `onDestroy()` method was not called because I used the "Clear memory" button in the Task Manager (Samsung Galaxy 2)

Comment: I've checked with a simple logcat line: `Log.i("OnDestroy: ", "Method Called");` This appears in my LogCat, so the method is called. I'm using a Samsung S3, and kill my application by holde the home button down, to see the recent apps and removing them.